# Perl Cassandra package in Windows

Tags: perl, cassandra

I already asked a question beofore about using perlcassa in Windows. I tried both Cassandra::Simple and Perlcassa drivers and both hadn't been built successfully over Windows.
My question now: is there any Perl driver for Cassansra (CQL or any driver) that works well in Windows?
I'm using Activestate perl in Windows 7 (64).

Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

You might try the `IO::Async`-driven `Net::Async::CassandraCQL`. The former should work now on Windows since version 0.61, and the latter is pure-perl with no weird system-level interaction, just plain network IO, so hopefully that combination should work.

Comment: As mentioned in http://code.activestate.com/ppm/Net-Async-CassandraCQL/ it couldn't compiled successfully in Windows

Comment: That's unfortunately the first time I've heard of that. I've now raised it as an RT bug - see https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=100965 for further communications